# Cannot install gem 'therubyracer' in OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mavericks

I am new to mac and tried to `bundle install` a cloned rails repo. I got an error while installing libv8 gem, googled and found a solution and did

```
brew install libv8
gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
```

Next I got struck at therebyracer gem, the full trace is as follows

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/anand/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
libtool: unrecognized option `-static'
libtool: Try `libtool --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [/Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/diy-fp.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fast-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fixed-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/once.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparse-data.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser-api.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/scanner.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/strtod.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/token.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/unicode.o
  CXX(target) /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/utils.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/anand/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

I think this is a problem with Mavericks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know what fixed my problem. I was trying everything and it got fixed.

I installed gcc47 using macports, not homebrew.(it took nearly 2 days to install in my slow 512kbps connection)

Then I changed the version of therubyracer to '0.12.0'

I don't know which got my problem fixed.

Comment: Was assisting someone through the issue of getting therubyracer installed as well and updating from version 0.11.4 to 0.12.0 got us past the problem as well.  I think in trying different solutions, we may have been using apple-gcc-42 at the time we successfully installed.

Comment: I did not have to install apple-gcc-42.  Moving to 0.12.x fixed the problem I had with compiling.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try what I summarized in this question: ["gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'" on osx mavericks not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630154/gem-install-therubyracer-v-0-10-2-on-osx-mavericks-not-installing/19762877)

```
brew install apple-gcc42

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2 /usr/bin/g++ 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2 /usr/bin/cpp

brew uninstall v8 (only in case you installed it with brew)
gem install libv8
gem install therubyracer
```

Let me know if this works! I've been dealing with the same problem since the launch of Mavericks :)

Comment: I tried those, but didn't work. I have answered my own question. sorry that I couldn't give a perfectly clear answer.

Comment: probably adding gcc42 (you said gcc47 but I guess you wanted to say gcc42, right?) did the trick

Comment: The libv8 gem (or at least 3.11.8.13) requires GCC 4.4+. Probably a bit of both gcc47 and later version of therubyracer fixed things?

Answer (score 1):

Now after installing v8 try to reinstall ruby.

```
rvm reinstall 2.0
```

And after that install therubyracer with `gem install therubyracer`

Comment: that didn't work. I get the same error. Isn't it a problem with GCC version..?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I upgraded from OSX Mountain Lion to OSX Mavericks.

Upgrading from ruby-1.8.7-p354 to ruby-1.8.7-375 did the trick for me.  Maybe upgrade your ruby 2.0.0-p125 to 2.0.0-rc2  (2.0 is above p353 already)

if you were using rbenv:

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-rc2
rbenv rehash
rbenv shell 2

bundle install
```

Answer (score -1):

```
gem uninstall libv8
brew rm v8
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install v8-315
brew link --force v8-315
gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer
```

With thanks to [DeLaGuardo](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/359)

Comment: `brew tap homebrew/dupes` is deprecated.