# therubyracer gem error on install - mac 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, therubyracer

I am trying to set up an existing project. When I run bundle install I get the following error on therubyracer gem:

```
Installing therubyracer (0.10.2)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling rr.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
rr.cpp:48:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_array.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_callbacks.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_context.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_date.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_debug.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_exception.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_exception.cpp:10:16: warning: unused variable 'stack' [-Wunused-variable]
  static void* stack[20];
               ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_external.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_external.cpp:10:9: warning: unused variable 'references' [-Wunused-variable]
  VALUE references;
        ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_function.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_handle.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_locker.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_locker.cpp:45:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
v8_locker.cpp:85:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling v8_message.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_object.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_object.cpp:77:19: warning: unused variable 'proto' [-Wunused-variable]
    Handle<Value> proto(rr_rb2v8(prototype));
                  ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_script.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_string.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_template.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_v8.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_value.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_value.cpp:100:9: warning: unused function 'ToInt32' [-Wunused-function]
  VALUE ToInt32(VALUE self) {
        ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_weakref.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
linking shared-object v8.bundle
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ianseabock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/lib/libv8/build/v8/libv8.a'
make: *** [v8.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ianseabock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ianseabock/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.10.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'" on osx mavericks not installing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630154/gem-install-therubyracer-v-0-10-2-on-osx-mavericks-not-installing)

Comment: You have to compile `libv8` with g++ 4.2, see the linked question for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

`Terminal`

```
gem uninstall libv8
```

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer'
bundle install
```

That's it. your libv8 and therubyracer version were not matching, so you were getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use ruby 2.2.0 and it should work.

For me it didn't work with ruby 2.1.x with any possible setting.
With ruby 2.2.0 it worked smoothly.