# Ruby on Rails - Installing therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, therubyracer, libv8

I was installing therubyracer and I got the following error:
  `ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`
I was looking at other posts from StackOverflow, but none of them changed this. 
I was using version '3.3.10.4' of libv8. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: So you already tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630154/gem-install-therubyracer-v-0-10-2-on-osx-mavericks-not-installing

Comment: either you've missed header, or have invalid gcc installation. provide the `mkmf.log`

Comment: you need to install the missing libraries which are the dependencies for this js complier gem rubyracer

Comment: what is the os you are using, it will help others to give clear answer

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 16